# L4 norm of Legendre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

The classical Legendre polynomials are the sequence of polynomials given by the recurrence
$$(k+1)P_{k+1}(x) = (2k+1)x P_k(x) - k P_{k-1}(x)$$
with initial conditions $P_0(x) = 1$ and $P_1(x) = 1$.
They satisfy
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_k(x) P_\ell(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{2k+1} \delta_{k\ell}$$
and there is also the uniform bound $|P_k(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.

I am interested in proving a bound on the L4 norm of these polynomials:
$$\|P_k\|_4 := \left(\int_{-1}^1 P_k(x)^4 \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/4}\,.$$
Using the uniform bound, it is trivial to show that
$$\|P_k\|_4^4 \leq \int_{-1}^1 P_k(x)^2 = O(k^{-1})\,,$$
but doing the integration for small values of $k$ suggests that actually a bound of the form $\|P_k\|_4^4 = O(k^{-2})$ should hold. I haven't been able to make any sort of inductive argument work.

**Question**: is it true that $\|P_k\|_4^4 = O(k^{-2})$?